# Using matplotlib and function animation Unable to rotate all the electrons in an atom model

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation

I am trying to create a matplotlib animation with points at N, W, E, S, NW, NE, SW, and SE to run in a loop (like 8 electrons in an atom shell). While N, W, E, and S are working, NW, NE, SW, and SE are not conforming to the same loop. Can somebody help with the transformations needed with some explanation?

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.clear()
ax.set_xlim(-4,4)
ax.set_ylim(-4,4)

shell2 = 14.5

largest = int(14.5*2)

difference = int(0-(largest))
difference2 = int(0+(largest))


def createList(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2+1)]


x = (createList(difference,difference2))
y = (createList(difference,difference2))


def rotate_anim():
  theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

  s2 = np.sqrt(shell2**2)
  s2x1 = s2*np.cos(theta)
  s2x2 = s2*np.sin(theta)
  ax.plot(s2x1,s2x2, color='k')
    
  theta2 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)


  x_e1s2 = shell2
  y_e1s2 = 0
  e1s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e1s2, y_e1s2, marker='.', color='r') 

  x_e2s2 = -shell2
  y_e2s2 = 0
  e2s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e2s2, y_e2s2, marker='.', color='k')

  x_e3s2 = 0
  y_e3s2 = shell2
  e3s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e3s2, y_e3s2, marker='.',  color='k')

  x_e4s2 = 0
  y_e4s2 = -shell2
  e4s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e4s2, y_e4s2, marker='.',  color='r')


  x_e5s2 = (shell2)*np.cos(45*0.0174533)
  y_e5s2 = (shell2)*np.sin(45*0.0174533)
  e5s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e5s2, y_e5s2, marker='.', markersize=20,  color='r')



  ax.set_aspect(1)


  plt.xlim(difference,difference2)
  plt.ylim(difference,difference2)




  def update(angle):

        r_ae = shell2
        x_ae = x_e1s2 + r_ae * np.cos(angle) - shell2 
        y_ae = y_e1s2 + r_ae * np.sin(angle)
        e1s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)

        r_ae = shell2
        x_ae = x_e2s2 - r_ae * np.cos(angle) + shell2 
        y_ae = y_e2s2 - r_ae * np.sin(angle)
        e2s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)

        r_ae =  shell2
        x_ae = x_e3s2 - r_ae * np.sin(angle) 
        y_ae = y_e3s2 + r_ae * np.cos(angle) - shell2 
        e3s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)

        r_ae =  shell2
        x_ae = x_e4s2 + r_ae * np.sin(angle) 
        y_ae = y_e4s2 - r_ae * np.cos(angle) + shell2 
        e4s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)


        # NOT WORKING - not running in the circular loop
        r_ae =  shell2
        x_ae = (shell2)*np.cos(45*0.0174533) + r_ae * np.sin(angle)  
        y_ae = (shell2)*np.sin(45*0.0174533) -  r_ae * np.cos(angle)  + shell2  
        e5s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)

        return e1s2_circlemove, e2s2_circlemove, e3s2_circlemove, e4s2_circlemove, e5s2_circlemove,

  plt.grid(False)
  plt.axis('off')
  anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=theta2, repeat=True)

  plt.show()

rotate_anim()
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. Below is the code.

'''

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

fig,ax = plt.subplots()
ax.clear()
ax.set_xlim(-4,4)
ax.set_ylim(-4,4)

shell2 = 14.5

largest = int(14.5*2)

difference = int(0-(largest))
difference2 = int(0+(largest))


def createList(r1, r2):
    return [item for item in range(r1, r2+1)]


x = (createList(difference,difference2))
y = (createList(difference,difference2))


def rotate_anim():
  theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

  s2 = np.sqrt(shell2**2)
  s2x1 = s2*np.cos(theta)
  s2x2 = s2*np.sin(theta)
  ax.plot(s2x1,s2x2, color='k')
    
  theta2 = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)

  x_e1s2 = shell2
  y_e1s2 = 0
  e1s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e1s2, y_e1s2, marker='.', color='r') 




  x_e3s2 = 0
  y_e3s2 = shell2
  e3s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e3s2, y_e3s2, marker='.',  color='k')



  x_e5s2 = (shell2)*np.cos(45*0.0174533)
  y_e5s2 = (shell2)*np.sin(45*0.0174533)
  e5s2_circlemove ,= ax.plot(x_e5s2, y_e5s2, marker='.',   color='r')



  ax.set_aspect(1)


  plt.xlim(difference,difference2)
  plt.ylim(difference,difference2)




  def update(angle):


        x_ae = shell2 + shell2 * np.cos(angle) - shell2 
        y_ae = 0 + shell2 * np.sin(angle)
        e1s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)


        x_ae = 0- shell2 * np.sin(angle) 
        y_ae = shell2 + shell2 * np.cos(angle) - shell2 
        e3s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)

        x_ae = (shell2 + shell2 * np.cos(angle) - shell2 + 0- shell2 * np.sin(angle) )*0.70710678118
        y_ae = (0 + shell2 * np.sin(angle)+shell2 + shell2 * np.cos(angle) - shell2)*0.70710678118
        e5s2_circlemove.set_data(x_ae, y_ae)

        return  e1s2_circlemove, e3s2_circlemove,  e5s2_circlemove,

  plt.grid(False)
  plt.axis('off')
  anim = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=theta2, repeat=True)

  plt.show()

rotate_anim();
```

'''